# Array formatting issue

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array in the below format.

```html
[
    {
      "TaskID": 303,
      "TaskName": "Test1",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": false,
      "RowNumber": 1
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 304,
      "TaskName": "Test2",
      "TaskType": "External",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": true,
      "RowNumber": 2
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 305,
      "TaskName": "Test3",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Error",
      "IsApproved": false,
      "RowNumber": 3
    }
  ]
```

I wanted to get the the TaskID in the below format

```html
"[303]","[304]","[305]"
```

Is it possible? if so please guide me.

I tried the below code, i am not getting the above format

```js
let selectedIds = this.arrayList.map(item => {
            return {
                TaskID: item.TaskID
            };
        })
```

Comment: You want to get a list of tasks _only_?

Comment: Please clarify what is your desired/target **format** - is it an 'Array of strings' where each string is enclosed in square-brackets? If so, it will need to be `[ "[303]", "[304]", "[305]" ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stackblitz [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5rabrl?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with all the ways to get it (see "console").

```
   let selectedIds1 = this.arrayList.map( item => "["+ item.TaskID +"]" );
    console.log(selectedIds1);

    let selectedIds2 = this.arrayList.map(item => item.TaskID);
    console.log(selectedIds2);

    let selectedIds3 = this.arrayList.map( item => [item.TaskID?.toString()] );
    console.log(selectedIds3);
```

[image: output]

If you want this output: ["[303]", "[304]", "[305]"]

```
let selectedIds1 = this.arrayList.map( item => "["+ item.TaskID +"]" );
console.log(selectedIds1);
// ["[303]", "[304]", "[305]"]
```

However, if you actually want this output, as I guess: [303,304,305]:

```
let selectedIds2 = this.arrayList.map(item => item.TaskID);

console.log(selectedIds2);
// [303,304,305]
```

If you want this output: [["303"],["304"],["305"]]

```
let selectedIds3 = this.arrayList.map( item => [item.TaskID?.toString()] );
console.log(selectedIds3);
// [["303"],["304"],["305"]]


NOTE: Remove .toString() if you want the id as number:
// [[303],[304],[305]]
```

Comment: I'm pleased it helped!